# mongodb query router setup issue with config file

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb v3.2.8 and setting up a query router for a mongo shard. I am using the following syntax inside the config file being used by the query router to specify the config servers (already running):

```
sharding:
   configDB: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx:27019,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27020
```

However, when I try to run the query router using this config file, I am getting the following error:

```
BadValue: Invalid configdb connection string: FailedToParse: invalid url [127.0.0.1:27019,127.0.0.1:27020]
```

Can anyone point to the correct syntax for specifying a list of config servers inside the config file being used to start the query routers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sharding:
  configDB: configReplSetName/cfg1.example.net:27017, cfg2.example.net:27017,...

details：
  [mongosReference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongos/)

Comment: But what is config server is not replica set?